# SceneKit - Setting overlaySKScene changing first responder?

Tags: swift, cocoa, scenekit

I'm very, very new to `SceneKit` and `SpriteKit`. I'm making a macOS game that relies on keyboard input, and overriding the `keyDown` function. Everything works fine, until I set `overlaySKScene` to a sort-of HUD scene. It seems once I add the overlay that my keyboard input is getting processed by the `SKScene` instead.

Here's the code I've tried using to keep key input going to my SCNScene:

```
if let overlayScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameOverlay.sks") {
    overlayScene.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    sceneView.overlaySKScene = overlayScene

    self.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

I've tried using the `self.becomeFirstResponder()` line in conjunction with overriding first responder functions in a custom SKScene class:

```
override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

But that overlay scene is still the one getting all key input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the userInteraction on your overlay:

```
let yourGameHudSKScene = .. setup your overlay SKScene


scnView.overlaySKScene = yourGameHudSKScene
yourGameHudSKScene.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: This didn't fix it. Disabling userInteraction on the overlay still has key input going to the overlay.

Comment: can you please update your question with relevant code?

Comment: please post also the code from your viewController where you override keyDown().  My suggestion should work with overlaySKScene, check this example from apple https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Badger/Listings/Common_View_swift.html

Comment: I followed the example from apple in your link and now everything's working. The KeyboardEventsDelegate protocol they use is what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: glad you worked it out, you're welcome! if it helped you, please accept the answer.